# CSS Hover Effect

Tags: css

I need to show an additional image once the user hovers over button. How would you go around doing this ideally just using CSS.

You can see what I need exactly on the image below, when the users hovers on the brochure button, the view brochure button appears.

[image]

Comment: The short answer `.button:hover .view-brochure {display:block}` We really need html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with css alone, if you can put an element inside the hovered object, you can do like this:

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q67hB/

html:

```
<div id="one">all the time
    <div id="two">only on hovering one</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#two{
  display: none;  
}
#one:hover #two{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your easy to use, and well explained answer :) Appreciate

Answer (score 0):

In CSS

```
button:hover {
    background-image: url(someImage.png);
}
```

Comment: I don't remember very well, but I think this does not (always) work in internet explorer. So you should test it well!

Comment: Apart from that, the other answer is better, especially to position, and play around.